# df result obviously wrong

Tags: disk-space

I just deleted a large (50 Gb) file and have emptied the recycle bin but `df -h` still reports my disk as only having 31Gi available.  As the result from `df` is effectively instantaneous it must be using a cached result.  What triggers it to bust the cache and update the result?  Can I trigger this manually?

Comment: Most probably this file is still open by a process. Then the allocated blocks have still a reference to them. This file might still be in your `~/.Trash` and you can check this hypothesis with `lsof +D ~/.Trash`. `+D` option mean search for the whole directory subtree starting at the following path.

Comment: Quick answer: no `df` result isn't wrong. It does simply show details the Finder GUI wants to hide from you.